# What do local network adversaires see?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, proxy

Suppose I am at an institution and download the Tor Browser (they now know I am using Tor) for research on a highly controversial subject.

If I use the downloaded Tor browser immediately and visit for example http://example.com (not https), what will the insitution know?
Also suppose I am connected to the through an ethernet cable, using their computer (assume they do not have their own certificate installed. that is I am not being MITM).

If they review their logs and no law enforcement is involved, what can they know?

Do they know I am viewing example.com or do they only know I am connected to a Tor node?

Can they see what I am viewing (the actually web content)?

What if I visit HTTPS websites?

Is there anything I should know before doing this research? (research is on legal stuff: *not* CP and the like)

Assume I will only visit clear text websites - not onion sites

I also do not care that they know I am using Tor

Answer (score 1):

This interactive infographic answers all your questions.

## https://www.eff.org/pages/tor-and-https

> Do they know I am viewing example.com

No

> or do they only know I am connected to a Tor node?

Yes

> Can they see what I am viewing (the actually web content)?

No

> What if I visit HTTPS websites?

Changes absolutely nothing with respect to local network adversaries.

> Is there anything I should know before doing this research?

That infographic. The [warnings on the Tor Browser download page](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html#warning).